# Alter REPL to display username, hostname and current working directory?

Tags: scheme, gnu, guile

In Guile's REPL the prompt is `scheme@(guile-user)>`, but I want it to show `my-name@hostname(current-working-directory)>`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IN system/repl/common in the guile scheme distribution you can see the repl-prompt implementation:

```
(define (repl-prompt repl)
  (cond
    ((repl-option-ref repl 'prompt)
     => (lambda (prompt) (prompt repl)))
    (else
      (format #f "~A@~A~A> " (language-name (repl-language repl))
        (module-name (current-module))
        (let ((level (length (cond
                              ((fluid-ref *repl-stack*) => cdr)
                              (else '())))))
          (if (zero? level) "" (format #f " [~a]" level)))))))
```

This indicates that you have a repl option 'prompt which is a lambda

```
(lambda (repl) ...)
```

(But it can also be a simple string) Than can outputs anything you want.

You have,

https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/System-Commands.html#System-Commands

so you can do

```
scheme@(guile-user)> ,option prompt ">"
>
>(+ 1 2)
$1 = 3
>,option prompt (lambda (repl) ">>")
>>(+ 2 3)
$2 = 5
>>
```

But what to do if you want to add the prompt in your .guile file?

If you put these inside .guile (before the prompt is created)

```
(use-modules (system repl common))
(repl-default-option-set! 'prompt ">>>")
```

you will get

```
>>> (+ 1 2)
3
```

You can create new repls as well, but that's for another question

For your specific example you can try

```
> ,option prompt (lambda (repl) 
                    (format #f "~a@~a(~a)>" 
                            (getenv "USER") 
                            (vector-ref (uname) 1) 
                            (getcwd)))
```

(but on one line) and get

```
 stis@lapwine(/home/stis/src/guile/module/system/repl)> (+ 1 2)
 3
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: `(getcwd)` returns the absolute path, which can get quite long. How do you just get the current directory?

Comment: (basename (getcwd))